# implementing google translate in a angular app

Tags: javascript, angular, google-translate

I'm trying to implement the google translate widget in my angular app, I managed to get the code provided by google to work by implementing it in the html index but I can't create a menu that directly opens the list with the languages

I tried to open the list element using javaScript

this is what i tried in my index html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="it">
<head>
  <style>
    /* Stile per l'icona del menu */
    .menu-icon {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
      background-color: #333;
      color: white;
      border-radius: 50%;
      cursor: pointer;
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 20px;
      right: 20px;
      z-index: 1000;
    }

    /* Stile per il widget di Google Traduttore */
    #google_translate_element {
      display: none;
    }

    /* Stile per il widget visibile */
    #google_translate_element.active {
      display: block;
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 80px;
      right: 20px;
      z-index: 1000;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="menu-icon" onclick="toggleTranslation()">
  <i class="fas fa-language"></i>
</div>
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>

<script>
  function toggleTranslation() {
    const element = document.getElementById('google_translate_element');
    element.classList.toggle('active');
    if (element.classList.contains('active')) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        const langList = element.querySelector('.goog-te-combo');
        if (langList) {
          langList.click();
        }
      }, 100);
    }
  }

  function googleTranslateElementInit() {
    new google.translate.TranslateElement({
      pageLanguage: 'it',
      autoDisplay: true,
      layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.HORIZONTAL
    }, 'google_translate_element');
  }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>

<app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

but when I click the menu button, the button to select the google languages ​​is displayed and not the list directly

following the screenshot
[screenshot.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLlhJ.png)

Comment: Please update and include the screenshot. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask